# Determine if text returned in MYSQL query is the default text

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Is there a way to easily determine if the text being returned by a query is the default text put in place when the database was created?

For example, the db I'm working with has several text fields that, when the db was set up, are pre-populated with greek ('lorem ipsum...'). But, each field is a little different in the amount of greek and what greek is used in the default. Without knowing the precise greek that is used in each field as the default, is there a way to have the query 'tell' me that it's the default text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<cfdbinfo />` to get this information.  You would use it as follows:

```
<cfdbinfo type="columns" name="qResult" table="tableName" datasource="dsnName" />
<cfdump var="#qResult#" />
```

In my tests, this returns a query with a "column_default_value" column that you can use to determine if the result is the default value or not.

You can find more info about cfdbinfo [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7685.html)

Comment: Thank you, Sean. I didn't know that kind of option even existed. Looks like there are some other great tools in the `cfdbinfo` tag.